# Вывод матрицы на консоль в виде пирамиды

Tags: java, матрицы

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Не могу придумать, как можно заполнить двумерный массив в java в виде пирамиды и вывести этот массив на экран, как показано выше в примере.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задачка довольно тривиальная и немного математическая:

```
public static int[][] pyramideMatrix(int cells) {

    int dim = cells * cells;

    int[][] arr = new int[dim][dim];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            int ii;
            int ij;

            if (i < dim/2) {
                ii = Math.min(i, j);
            } else {
                ii = Math.min(dim - 1 - i, j);
            }

            if (j < dim/2) {
                ij = Math.min(i, j);
            } else {
                ij = Math.min(i, dim - 1 - j);
            }

            arr[i][j] = Math.min(ii, ij);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Вот пример:

```
int[][] matrix = pyramideMatrix(3);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int[] arr: matrix) {
    sb.append(Arrays.toString(arr)).append('\n');
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

Вывод в консоль:

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Да, это правильно работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сделал более лаконичную и удобную версию.

```
public int[][] generate(int x, int y) {
            int[][] array = new int[x * 2][y * 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                int[] miniArr = array[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < miniArr.length; j++) {

                    int ii = (i < x) ? min(i, j) : min(j, x * 2 - i - 1);
                    int ij = (j < y) ? min(i, j) : min(i, y * 2 - j - 1);

                    miniArr[j] = min(ii, ij);
                }
            }
            return array;
        }
```